# Layout and Regions using require js, Backbone, Marionette and Underscore js

Tags: marionette

I am trying to get to grips with Backbone and Require JS using marionette for some of its excellent features. However I am finding a few issues with the app being available to render views in a template :

Here is my Js file :

```
define(
    ['jquery',
     'bootstrap',
     'backbone',
     'marionette',
     'jquery-ui',
     'text!templates/admin/home.html',
     'js/views/admin/sidebar',
     'js/views/admin/mainContent'
    ], 
    function(
        $,
        Bootstrap,
        Backbone, 
        Marionette,
        JqueryUI,
        ViewMainLayout,
        ViewSidebarMenu,
        ViewMainContent
    ) {
        var TestApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

        TestApp.addInitializer(function(){
            var layoutView = new AppLayoutView();
            layoutView.render();
            TestApp.appRegion.show(layoutView);

            layoutView.menu.show(ViewSidebarMenu);
            layoutView.content.show(ViewMainContent);
        });


         var AppLayoutView = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
             template: "#layoutPage",

             regions: {
                 menu: "#sideMenuBar",
                 content: "#MainContent"
              }
          });



        TestApp.addRegions({
            appRegion: "#homepage"
         });

        TestApp.start();
});
```

Here is my html file :

```
<div id="homepage"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="layoutPage">       

<div id="sideMenuBar"> --- Loading Sidebar Menu --- </div>

<div id="MainContent"> --- Loading Content --- </div>

<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
</script>
```

The browser console throws me the error: 
Error: Could not find template: '#homepage' in backbone.js file.

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious what's causing your problem - backbone couldn't find `#homepage` in your html. I assume that when you say "Here is my html file" you are referring to your template (`text!templates/admin/home.html`) and not the html at the page loaded by the browser? If that's the case, then it's important to note that nowhere in your view do you load anything from your template into the DOM, and that's probably why Marionette can't find it.

There are a few approaches for how to do this in combination with requireJS, but I usually just load the template them directly into the DOM using jQuery like so:

```
$("body").after(ViewMainLayout)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. As per your suggestion, i directly loaded the template into the DOM and got Error: Cannot render the template since it's false, null or undefined.

Comment: I think his html is referring to index.html i.e. what's already on the page. Since he declares the #layoutPage template via <script type="text/template" id="layoutPage">

Comment: Oops i take that back, it does seem like it's the content of text!templates/admin/home.html